# Confusion regarding Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

I calculated $[x,a^\dagger a]$ first by giving  a test function:

\begin{align}
[x,a^\dagger a]|\psi\rangle & =(xa^\dagger a-a^\dagger ax)|\psi\rangle \\ 
(xa^\dagger a-a^\dagger ax)|\psi\rangle&
=xa^\dagger a|\psi\rangle -a^\dagger ax|\psi\rangle\, , \\
&=xn|\psi\rangle-a^\dagger a|\psi'\rangle\\
&=n|\psi'\rangle-n|\psi'\rangle=0
\end{align} that is;
$[x,a^\dagger a]=0$ (where $x |\psi\rangle$=$|\psi'\rangle$ and $x$ and $p$ are operators)

But when I solved it explicitly by converting $a^\dagger a$ in terms of $x$ and $p$ and then substituting I got the answer as :
$[x,a^\dagger a]$=$ip$.
Which one is correct and why the other method is faulty?

Comment: What guarantee do you have that $x|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $a^\dagger a$?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are writing $x|\psi\rangle =|\psi'\rangle$ and assuming $|\psi\rangle $ is an eigenstate of $a^\dagger a$ with eigenvalue $n$. This does not imply, however that $\psi'\rangle $ is an eigenstate of $a^\dagger a$, so your second last step is invalid

Comment: More importantly, "test functions" should be arbitrary, they can't be cherry picked. Meaning that there is no reason that $|\psi\rangle$ should be an eigenstate of $a^\dagger a$ either!

Comment: @ZeroTheHero That's what I said in my second comment (and in my answer)! :)

Comment: @Philip I clearly need more coffee and less beer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I described in the comments, you've made some assumptions that are not allowed. The "test functions" you choose should be arbitrary, they can't be cherry-picked, meaning that there is no reason for $|\psi\rangle$ or $x|\psi\rangle$ to be an eigenstate of $a^\dagger a$.

Here's a quicker way to show it, if you're interested:

$$[\hat{x},\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}] = \frac{1}{\hbar \omega}[\hat{x},\hat{H}] = \frac{1}{\hbar \omega} \Big[\hat{x}, \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 x^2\Big] = \frac{1}{\hbar \omega} \Big[\hat{x}, \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}\Big] = \frac{i}{m\omega} \hat{p},$$

where I've used the fact that $[x,\hat{p}^2] = 2i\hbar\hat{p}$.